# What does 'go on' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Didn't Mr Blake make a fuss about us leaving that behind. Yeah He does  **go on** . Anyway it was  easy  to get one  from another of  the  students.

Comment: I want to clarify, is it "He does. Go on.", or " He does go on."? It might be helpful if you include who said what, or [line breaks](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4798/36187).

Comment: More context would be helpful here.

Comment: he does go on. It's about 2 students discussing what happened in their field trip. And they forgot  the string, so "he" is their teacher. I am  confused whether their teacher did complain on that or not.

Comment: Yes, "Mr Blake" complained (made a fuss) about the forgotten string.

Comment: Unless a source for this text is added (as per the answer below), this could be considered plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "he does go on" is commonly used to mean "he talks (or writes) at excessive length" (possibly about a specific subject).

So I think the speaker here is saying  that Mr Blake talked (scolded) far too long about "leaving that behind".

The added context seems to confirm my view.

---

I find that the original appears to be from [this site](https://mini-ielts.com/391/view-solution/listening/rocky-bay-field-trip)

and looked like this:

> HELEN:
>
> But not the piece of string to hold up in the air! Didn’t Mr Blake make a fuss about us leaving that behind.
>
> COLIN:
>
> Yeah. He does go on. Anyway it was easy to get one from another of the students.